# Why do Hindus touch Earth before starting the day?

Tags: rituals, earth

Before starting the day, or keeping feet on Earth, Hindus usually touch Earth by their hands. What could be the possible reasons behind this ritual?

Is this to show respect to Earth?

Comment: Not sure but I don't do that

Comment: @Mr.Alien but i have seen many people do that.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: It is a common practice among Hindus. Wondering why did you just say like that being a Hindu. Once you understand the reason, I am sure, you will do that.

Comment: @ArunningMind Yea, thats the reason am here, wanna learn more about our religion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purusha Suktham and Sri Vishnu Sahasra namas say the earth His feet. That is why we bow to the earth, as it amounts to touching the Lord. Another reason is Bhoomi or Bhoomadevi is the consort Sri Mahavishnu - Both the Bhagavatha Purana and Sshasranama tells about this. Mahavishnu is called Madhini pathi (husband of Bhooma devi). It is like touching the feet of one's own mother. For mother gets the top priority in the order of reverence (mathru devo bhava, next comes father Pirthu devo bhava, next comes the teacher Acharya devo Bhava and lastly the God.
Mother is the own who gave you the biological form, father leads by example, teacher shows the world and lastly God enables you to merge with Him.

Comment: It would be more useful to cite/quote exact verses of the suktas mentioned

Answer (score 8):

> samudravasane devi
>   parvatasthana mandale
>   vishnupatni namastubhym
>   padasparsam kshamasva me

O Goddess, who dwells in the Oceans,
who's life-giving breasts are the mountains.
Salutations to the wife of Lord Vishnu,
Forgive me for the sin of touching you with my feet.

-[*Bhoomi vandanam*](http://rare-news-collection.blogspot.in/2009/03/bhoomi-vandanam.html)

Among traditional South Indian Brahmins, it is customary to recite this verse before rising from bed. You touch the earth and seek forgiveness from Bhu Devi for stepping on her.